My Power Automate email has no attachment contents
I'm currently developing a little power automate script to check email sent to my inbox to copy their file attachments into a sharepoint directory. The first step works well, but when I try to access the ContentBytes property of the attachment, I get a null result, no matter what I do.
Debugging the problem further, I can inspect the json representation of the email, more specifically the attachment part of it :
        "attachments": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                "id": "ABCDEFGHIJxN2YxZDY4LTg2NGUtNGFlZC05MjkxLTk1YmNmYTExNGMwYQBGAAAAAAB1UPP0g57US79cXWoM-hy1BwBhkDNeBn4nSJmQYzPajI3HAAFQsVWPAABhkDNeBn4nSJmQYzPajI3HAASUk_4TAAABEgAQACblboGchHNFiYfGDjE7atU=",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-05-22T02:41:24+00:00",
                "name": "Myfile.xlsx",
                "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                "size": 184602,
                "isInline": false
            }
        ]

And sure enough, there are no ContentBytes property, despite what the docs are implying.
So my question is, how can I retrieve the content of these attachement in a Power Bi environment.
Thank you !

Could you share the query you are sending? I've an idea what wrong, but need to see more steps from your script.

Turns out all I needed was to turn on the IncludeAttachments in the Power Automate task. I only had the fetchOnlyWithAttachment option turned on.

there is a template for this scenario in the PowerAutomate portal, named "Save email attachments to a SharePoint library and receive a notification". This is not the same what you want to achieve, but you can see here the required steps and actions.
BTW there is no need for "contentbytes", you need only "File Name" and "File Content"
